# Superposing two plots with a colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I've got two axes which I'm superposing on top of each other. The top axis requires a colorbar, but when I add one in it shifts the top axis to the side so the plots are no longer on top of each other. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

size = 100

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)  #, sharex=True)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor="none")
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
ax1.axis("off")
ax2.axis("off")

data1 = np.array([[num for num in range(size)] for num in range(size)])
data2 = np.random.random((10, 10))

print(data2)

ax1.imshow(data1, origin = "lower")
contourplot = ax2.contourf(data2, cmap = plt.cm.jet, alpha = 0.5)
plt.colorbar(contourplot)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You should leave out `ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor="none")` and reuse `ax1` for everything. Further, you need to set the extent in `ax1.imshow(data1, origin="lower", extent=[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])`

Comment: Thanks, this code was used to take snapshots from an animation where two axes were used (as only one was animated) but didn't occur to me that I only need one now; thanks